# "Export to Zeplin" Feature Not Showing Up on Adobe XD in Windows 10

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-xd

I have designed a landing page with Adobe XD. Now, I need to convert it to HTML5. So, I would like to use Zeplin. But "Export to Zeplin" feature is not showing up on Adobe XD. However, it is working perfectly on Adobe Photoshop. How can I fix the issue?

Comment: This sounds like a tech support question. Generally these are off-topic here on GDSE. If I were you, I'd try to get some support from the plugin developers.